# C# OdbcCommand. Rounding values when they are -10

Tags: c#, rounding, bde

```
odbcConnection1.ConnectionString = "PageTimeout=3000000;UserCommitSync=Yes;MaxScanRows=7;DefaultDir=" +
    (((fMain)MdiParent).PathDBF) +
    ";DriverID=21;Deleted=1;Statistics=0;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL=dBase III;" +
    "Driver={Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)}";
odbcConnection1.Open();  
odbcCreate.CommandText = insert into YYMMKOD_EDRPOU (CDPR, IDCODE, FIO, PPOS, RS, YEARIN, MONTHIN, LGCODE, DATA1, DATA2, LGKOL, LGKAT, LGPRC, SUMM, FACT, TARIF, FLAG) + "values('25652927', '2951616474', 'text text text', 'ВТ 001511', '267066', '2014', '06', '504', '01.06.2013', '31.07.2013', 10, 35, 50.00, -11.020000, 0, 0.259200, 1)";       
odbcCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
odbcConnection1.Close();
```

I fill DBF file with some values​​, but when filling column sum (numeric field) and if the value of -10 or more, then the value is rounded. how to disable the rounding?
For example, I fill the summ field -11.02 and -11.00 is recorded in dbf.

Comment: How **exactly** is `SUMM` declared (what is the **exact** column type, including any precision / scale numbers), and what is the database engine here?

Comment: In dbf summ declared -  SUMM,N,5,2

Comment: *resolved* in numeric field (5,2) value bigger than -10 just can not fit in that field. need to use at least numeric(6,2)

Answer (score 0):

resolved. in numeric field (5,2) value bigger than -10 just can not fit. need to use at least numeric(6,2)